# Where to call SendMessageUpwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I'd like to use the SendMessageUpwards() method, but I have no idea on where to call it.
The problem is, I want to send the message upwards every time the message is received.
So right now, I do this.

```
MessageToSendToParentObject()
{
    SendMessageUpwards("MessageToSendToParentObject", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

But then every time the message is received by this child object, I get a StackOverflowException.
So how or where do I use this SendMessageUpwards() method if I want to send a message upwards every time its received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GameObject.SendMessageUpwards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessageUpwards.html) is not for your gameobject parent. Is for all Monobehaviours of all actives gameobjects existing in your Project.
Instead of [GameObject.SendMessageUpwards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessageUpwards.html) use [GameObject.SendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html), to call a Method in all Monobehaviours of your gameobject.

Example:

```
void Click()
{
    /// Calls the function MessageToSend without options
    SendMessage("MessageToSend", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}

// Every script attached to the game object
// that has a MessageToSend function will be called.
void MessageToSend()
{
    Debug.Log(transform.name & " got the message");
}
```

Comment: @joreldraw Thank you, didn't know SendMessageUpwards() would send that message to every gameObject. But my question remains, where would I call SendMessage() so it sends that particular message EVERY TIME it's received?

Comment: Edit: The documentation says this:
"Calls the method named methodName on every MonoBehaviour in this game object and on every ancestor of the behaviour." This doesn't mean it's called on every Monobehaviour in the project, but rather on every MonoBehaviour parent or ancestor of the game object that's receiving the method, right?

Comment: @Thrindil you call a method with sendmessage, you can put this call in an event if this is what i understand for "EVERY TIME it's received" to not join in stack overflow. Tell me if this is ok and i complete the Answers with an example.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I think I need your example to fully comprehend what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

[`SendMessageUpwards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessageUpwards.html), according to the docs:

> Calls the method named methodName on every MonoBehaviour **in this game object** and on every ancestor of the behaviour.

Bold for emphasis. Your method that is calling `SendMessageUpwards` is inadvertently calling itself, this is what is resulting in the Stack Overflow.

To fix your problem, I suggest never using SendMessage or its siblings. Instead just get or have a direct reference to the object you want to invoke a method on, and call it directly. eg:

```
this.transform.parent.GetComponent<ZhuLi>().DoTheThing();
```